# Click one element from many elements

Tags: jquery

i know it may be easy thing for you but i dont know how find a solution, when i click an "edit" button i want to remove only the text next to the button and not all of them .. how would i do it ?

```js
     $(document).ready(function () {
        $("a").click(function () {
            click()
        })
    })

    function click() {
        var text = $(".text").text();
        alert(text)
        $(".text").remove();
        $(".contenu").prepend("<input class='input' type='text'>")
        $("input").val(text)
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="new">
    <div class="contenu" style="margin: 40px;">
        <p style="padding:0; margin:0; float: left;" class="text">Text</p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="">edit</a>
    </div>

    <div class="contenu" style="margin: 40px;">
        <p style="padding:0; margin:0; float: left;" class="text">Text</p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="">edit</a>
    </div>

</section>
```

Thank you for your help

Comment: `$("input").val(text)` <-- that selects all inputs in the page...

Comment: As an aside, note that if the only thing your click handler does is call the `click()` function you don't need the anonymous function wrapper, you can just say `$("a").click(click)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are trying to achieve can be done in a single line:

```
$(this).parent().prepend('<input type="text">').find('.text').remove();
```

And this is how it would work for this purpose (you would need to change "Edit" to "Save" afterwards, but that is another topic)

```js
$('a').click(function(event) { 
  event.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().prepend('<input type="text">').find('.text').remove();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section id="new">
    <div class="contenu" style="margin: 40px;">
        <p style="padding:0; margin:0; float: left;" class="text">Text</p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a class="edit" href="">edit</a>        
    </div>

    <div class="contenu" style="margin: 40px;">
        <p style="padding:0; margin:0; float: left;" class="text">Next</p>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <a href="">edit</a>
    </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are currently doing is that you are selecting all `.text`s in the page:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("a").click(function () {
      click()
  })
})

function click() {
  var text = $(".text").text();
  alert(text)
  $(".text").remove();
  $(".contenu").prepend("<input class='input' type='text'>")
  $("input").val(text)
}
```

to be able to achieve your desired output you should change the way `click()` was handled:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $("a").click(function () {
      // find text if there is one
      var text = $(this).find(".text").text();
      // get the parent of this element where the click orignated.
      var parent = $(this).parent(".contenu");
      // find a .text element inside parent
      $(parent).find(".text").remove();
      // add it
      $(parent).prepend("<input class='input' type='text'>");
      // set the value
      if (text) {
           // make sure text is not undefined
           $(parent).find("input").val(text);
      }
  })
})
```

hope that helps.

Comment: do not forget to mark it as an answer if it does help, have a nice day

Comment: There was no need to repeat *all* of the OP's JS: just noting that `$(".text").` selects all such elements would've been enough.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`.next()`](http://api.jquery.com/next/) in jQuery to access next element to the selector. since you are handing event through JavaScript binding you can do `$(this).next()` in your button click code.

Comment: @TaouBen In your code you have <p> tag before the anchor so you can use .prev()

Comment: Thank you.. i'll keep it in mind because i found an other solution

Answer (score 0):

```
$('a').click(function() {
    $(this).closest('div').find('p.text').remove();
});
```